# General equation of line

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

Why can't the general equation of line (Ax+By+C=0)take both x and y values as 0, although practically a line might pass through 0,0?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is because the straight line does not have to pass through the origin in order to be valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "*both $x$ and $y$ values as $0$*"? The general equation of a line is typically written as $y=mx+b$, so are you saying that a line has an equation of $0=m0+b$?

Comment: This question would be better if you edited it to show (1) what you think "the general equation of line" is and (2) specifically why you think this equation cannot take both $x$ and $y$ as $0$.

Comment: I am referring to Ax+By+C= 0 as the general equation of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a line is typically written as $y=mx+b$. This equation **can** take both $x$ and $y$ values as $0$. For example, consider the line $y=\frac{1}{3}x$ (i.e. taking $m=\frac{1}{3}$ and $b=0$). Clearly, $x=y=0$ is possible. However, do note that an equation can take both $x$ and $y$ values as $0$ if and only if $b=0$.

If you're asking why $x$ and $y$ can't both be $0$ when the line is written in the formula $ax+by+c=0$, $x$ and $y$ **can** both be $0$ if and only if $c=0$. This is because if $x=y=0$, then you have $c=0$, and if you have $c=0$, then $x=y=0$ will be possible in the original equation.